# Google anayltics activate storage afterwards

Tags: javascript, google-analytics

To prevent Google Analytics of settings any cookies before a user accepts it (GDPR), I use `analytics.js` method base on [GA Docs](https://developers.google.com/analytics/devguides/collection/analyticsjs/cookies-user-id#disabling_cookies):

```
ga('create', '####MyCode####', {
    'storage': 'none'
});
```

Is there a way to reactive it on runtime (after user accepts the cookies)? Something like

```
ga('set', 'storage', true);
```

Comment: Was any solution found for this? It looks like the Jul 28th answer to call the "send" method didn't fully fit what was asked.

Comment: No, I didn't found an answer.

Answer (score 0):

My advise is to call “send” method only when you have required consent.

i.e.:

```
if (document.cookie.indexOf('consent_cookie_name=')  > -1)  {
        ga('create', 'UA-XXXXXXXX-X', 'auto');
        ga('send', 'pageview');
    }
```

Comment: I know, that I COULD do that, but thats not what I was looking for. With this, I will not count visitors, which do not make any decission at all.